# Are there default states in Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Testing the next controller, I've found that emits states that I'm not emitting explicitly.

The case is at the beginning of the build method where I don't set the loading state. At the same time, when the logout method is called, it emits again the data state.

Is that an expected behavior? I put print statements so is easier to follow; the controller is designed in a this way to load the user data when it is initialized.

Riverpod version: ^2.4.9

Code

```dart
@riverpod
class SettingsController extends _$SettingsController {
  @override
  FutureOr<AppUser?> build() async {
    try {
      final currentUser = await _getCurrentUser();
      state = AsyncValue.data(currentUser);
    } catch (e, st) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, st);
      return null;
    }
    return state.value;
  }

  Future<bool> logout() async {
    try {
      await _logout();
      state = const AsyncValue.data(null);
      return true;
    } catch (e, st) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, st);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```bash
Logs:
✅ build: starts
AsyncLoading<AppUser?>()
✅ build: try
AsyncLoading<AppUser?>()
✅ logout: starts
AsyncLoading<AppUser?>()
✅ build: try: after getting user
AsyncData<AppUser?>(value: AppUser(UserUid, test@test.com, 1234mauro, Bobby, Axelrod, 123456789, false))
✅ logout: try
AsyncData<AppUser?>(value: AppUser(UserUid, test@test.com, 1234mauro, Bobby, Axelrod, 123456789, false))
✅ logout: logout successful
AsyncData<AppUser?>(value: null)
```

Tests

```dart
test('When correctly triggered, Then should emit loading and data',
          () async {
        // * arrange
        when(() => getCurrentUserUsecase())
            .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value(testUser));
        when(() => logoutUsecase()).thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value());

        final container = makeProviderContainer(
          logoutUsecase,
          deleteUsecase,
          reauthenticateUsecase,
          getCurrentUserUsecase,
        );

        final listener = Listener<AsyncValue<AppUser?>>();

        container.listen(
          settingsControllerProvider,
          listener.call,
          fireImmediately: true,
        );
        const loading = AsyncLoading<AppUser?>();
        const data = AsyncData<AppUser?>(testUser);
        const nullData = AsyncData<AppUser?>(null);

        // * act
        final controller = container.read(settingsControllerProvider.notifier);
        final result = await controller.logout();

        // * assert
        expect(result, true);
        verifyInOrder([
          () => listener(null, loading),
          () => listener(loading, data),
          () => listener(data, data),
          () => listener(data, nullData),
        ]);

        verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
      });
```

Comment: `final currentUser = await _getCurrentUser();` while in that step, the state will be Loading.  This is natural.